Can't get string from Powershell Windows Form Textbox
So, I have been working on a GUI for one of my scripts at my work place, and I can't get any string of text from a textbox which the user can put text into. I have created a barebones version of what I want to do to try to solve this problem. I have the "OK" button set to Write-Host $input.text when clicked.  When I click "OK", the console just outputs nothing, a single space.
I have tried rearranging my code, adding -Out-String, and adding .ToString() which ends up saying that the input is null. Even when I set the text to something such as "Test" when the script is ran, the output is still null.
Here is my code:
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load('System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load('System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089')
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form -Property @{
Name = 'Test'
Text = 'Test'
}


$input = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox -Propert @{
    Name = "Input"
    Size = "200,200"
} #Input Textbox

$confirm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button -Property @{
    Text = "Ok"
    Name = "confirm"
    Location = "0,210"
} #confirm button

$close = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button -Property @{
    Text = "Close"
    Name = "Close"
    Location = "100,210"
} #close button

$confirm.Add_Click($run)

$close.Add_Click($exit)


$form.Controls.Add($confirm)
$form.Controls.Add($close)
$form.Controls.Add($input)

$run = {Write-Host $input.Text} #Output input box text


$exit = {
$form.Close()
}

$form.ShowDialog()
$form.BringToFront()

If I can just get the text from the input box, then I am good to go, as I all need is a string from the user for what I need to do. I also want to stick to this method of using Windows Forms, as my form in full form is gonna be complicated.

The issue with your code is that the callbacks ($run and $exit) are defined after you add them instead of before, so you're essentially adding null to those .Click events. Change the order, define them before and it will be good.
Also, the use of $input as variable name is not recommended. $input is an automatic variable in PowerShell.
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load('System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load('System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089')
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form -Property @{
    Name = 'Test'
    Text = 'Test'
}

$textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox -Propert @{
    Name = 'Input'
    Size = '200,200'
} #Input Textbox

$confirm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button -Property @{
    Text     = 'Ok'
    Name     = 'confirm'
    Location = '0,210'
} #confirm button

$close = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button -Property @{
    Text     = 'Close'
    Name     = 'Close'
    Location = '100,210'
} #close button

$run = { Write-Host $textBox.Text } #Output input box text
$exit = {
    $form.Close()
}

$confirm.Add_Click($run)
$close.Add_Click($exit)
$form.Controls.Add($confirm)
$form.Controls.Add($close)
$form.Controls.Add($textBox)
$form.Add_Shown({ $this.Activate() })
$form.ShowDialog()


Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed, I'll be more better about my ordering then. Also thank you letting me know that info about $input.

You can shorten this considerably. Note that a call to ShowDialog sends a return value which needs to be tested to see which buttom was pressed, as shown in the following working example:
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load('System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load('System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089')
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form -Property @{
Name = 'Test'
Text = 'Test'
}

$textbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox -Property @{
    Name = "Input"
    Location = "10, 10"
    Size = "200,200"
} #Input Textbox

$okbutton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button -Property @{
    Text = "OK"
    Name = "confirm"
    Location = "10,210"
    DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
} # OK button for the dialog

$form.Controls.Add($textbox)
$form.Controls.Add($okbutton)

$result = $form.ShowDialog()
# check the return value from ShowDialog, and capture the input(s)
if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $ans = $textbox.Text
     Write-Host $ans
}

